# Returning 400 BAD REQUEST on each POST - fosrestbundle, Symfony3

Tags: json, fosrestbundle, symfony

I am using **fosrestbundle** on **Symfony3** to create a server side web-api.

*fos_rest* configuration of *app/config/config.yml*

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
            enabled: true
            rules:
                - { path: ^/api, priorities: [ json ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml: true
            json : true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

Whenever I am posting with **Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded** the Controller get hit. Each time I use **application/json** the response is **400 BAD REQUEST**. But I need it to be **Content-Type: application/json**. Please tell me what should I change in ***fos_rest*** config so that it can accept **application/json**. Thanks in advance.

N.B. I tried [Body Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/body_listener.html) by the book. But no luck. Version change may be the problem. I don't know.

Comment: It looks like the JSON that you send in the body of your request is not valid. How does your complete request look like?

Comment: yeah... its my mistake. I was trying with **Advanced Rest Client Application** Google Chrome Extension. I was sending post by form data but not json formatter. My BAD. Thanks anyway.@xabbuh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @xabbuh mentioned, you are trying with wrong data format while requesting.

[image]

Instead of above, your request should look like this.

[image]